# What makes my projection that slow?

Tags: mongodb

Hi somehow projections make my queries slower.

This is my query:

```
{
    "$and": [{
        "$or": [{
            "tiles": "18-137068-57860"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137068-57861"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137068-57862"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137068-57863"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137068-57864"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137068-57865"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137068-57866"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137069-57860"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137069-57861"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137069-57862"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137069-57863"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137069-57864"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137069-57865"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137069-57866"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137070-57860"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137070-57861"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137070-57862"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137070-57863"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137070-57864"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137070-57865"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137070-57866"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137071-57860"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137071-57861"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137071-57862"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137071-57863"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137071-57864"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137071-57865"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137071-57866"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137072-57860"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137072-57861"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137072-57862"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137072-57863"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137072-57864"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137072-57865"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137072-57866"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137073-57860"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137073-57861"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137073-57862"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137073-57863"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137073-57864"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137073-57865"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137073-57866"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137074-57860"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137074-57861"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137074-57862"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137074-57863"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137074-57864"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137074-57865"
        }, {
            "tiles": "18-137074-57866"
        }]
    }, {
        "lastupdate": {
            "$gte": 0
        }
    }]
}
```

and this is my projection:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "_owner": 1,
    "destination": 1,
    "endtime": 1,
    "position": 1,
    "speed": 1,
    "starttime": 1,
    "angle": 1,
    "mapspeed": 1,
    "vehicleClass": 1,
    "target": 1,
    "lastupdate": 1,
    "createdate": 1,
    "hp": 1,
    "lastshot": 1,
    "geobinding": 1
}
```

with projection the query runs 6secs, without 77ms

i'm running mongodb 3.0.3

EDIT:
it seems that "_id" : 1 in the projections slows it down, when i remove it, it is fas tas well, but why?

Comment: Consider using [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

Comment: tiles is a sub-collection, does $in work for that?

Comment: you don't need `$or` and `$and`. a simple regex can replace your `$or`

Comment: do regex work for indexed fields?

Comment: yes it does http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use

Comment: The `_id` field is, by default, included in the result set so there's no need to explicitly project it with `_id:1`.

Comment: @chridam yes i found that out too - but why does it slow down the query? it seems to be a bug